# Basic while loop with lists

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I'm stuck on a question in my programming class, it asks:

"Using a while loop, write a function find_index(items, target) that returns the index of the first occurrence of the target in the list items. If the target isn't in the list, your function should return -1. Your function may not use the built-in list method list.index"

So far I have:

```
def find_index(items, target):
    """Returns the index of the first occurrence of the target in the list"""
    i = 0 
    while i < len(nums):
        return (items[0])
    if target not in items:
        return items[-1]
```

With the following test, the result should be 1. However I am getting 10, any pointers where I've gone wrong?

```
nums = [10, 20, 30]
i = find_index(nums, 20)
print(i)
```

Comment: That function isn't anywhere close to the goal. `return` immediately ends the function and always returns the first item from the list, unconditionally.

Comment: Your code will enter the `while` loop and then immediately return the first item from `items`. Even if that loop was fixed, if it doesn't find `target` in the list then it will return the last item from the list instead of just returning -1 as the question asks.

Comment: You're supposed to return *the index*, in other words `i`, not `items[...]`. You also need to *increment `i`* somewhere in the loop. You also need an `if items[i] == target` somewhere. You also want to refer to `len(items)`, not `len(nums)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your question can be easily given, but before that please do understand how the parameters work in a function.

```py
def my_function(foo):
    print(foo)
    foo = "Hi, I'm changed"
    return foo

foo = "hello"
print(my_function(foo), foo)
```

Basically, you are defining a variable `foo` and in the argument, you have given the same name. So, when you change the variable inside the function it does not change the variable outside of its scope.

```
hello
("Hi, I'm changed", 'hello')
```

**Problimatically** you have defined arguments as `item` and `target` in your function, but you are actually using the variable `nums` defined outside.

### Finding Index using a `while` Loop

Before proceeding to the problem, note the following:

1. A `while` loop will continue until a certain "condition" is met. So it **is your duty** to stop the *while-loop* from running forever.
2. A function stops its execution when a `return` is received.

So, you will have to modify your `while` loop to check *for each element if it is equal to target* or not, or simply:

```py
while i < len(items):
    if items[i] == target:
        return i
    i += 1 # same as i = i + 1
```

Here the `index` that you are looking for is the `i`-th value. **Note** indexing starts from `0` in python.

Given this, you should be able to complete your homework. Just for the sake, here is the complete solution.

```py
def find_index(items, target):
    i = 0
    while i < len(items):
        if items[i] == target:
            return i
        i += 1 # increment i (as it is not done automatically)
    return -1

nums = [10, 20, 30]
i = find_index(nums, 20)
print(i)

>> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
def find_index(items, target):
    """Returns the index of the first occurrence of the target in the list"""
    i = 0 
    if target not in items:
        return -1
    while i < len(nums):
        if items[i] == target:
            return i
        i+=1
```

Comment: Just replacing `return (items[0])` with `return items[i]` won't change anything about the behaviour here. There are a lot more changes needed than that.

Comment: @deceze adding conditional statements will fix the problem, my answer has been edited to indicate this.

Comment: That's still not enough. Write it, try it.

Comment: The `not in` command will search for the element `x` within `items`. This might give a proper output, but I don't think this is how you should use a  `not in` condition checking inside a `while` loop.

Comment: Yes, now it works. Though the `target not in items` check is IMO superfluous, as it causes you to iterate the list twice in the end. You just need `return -1` after the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_index(items, target):
    i = 0
    while i < len(items):
        if items[i] == target:
            return i
        i += 1

    return -1


items = [10, 20, 30]
print(find_index(items, 0)) # for fail case, returns -1
print(find_index(items, 10)) # for successful case, returns 0 e.g.
```